# requirejs race condition - how to block until previous file retrieved

Tags: javascript, requirejs, race-condition

`common_tempaltes` file is not a requirejs file - rather a file that defines a global variable.

`common_templates` needs `hogan`. they both are requested more or less at the same time, but race condition is in affect. `common_templates` sometimes wins so the code fails with "hogan not loaded yet".

```
require(['module1', 'hogan', 'common_templates'], function(Module){
    Module.do_stuff() // this module also requires hogan and common_templates to be loaded
});
```

other than nested require, is there a built in way to tell require to block until `hogan` is fully downloaded?

nested:

```
require(['hogan'], function(Fn, Ui){
    require(['common_templates'], function(){
        require(['module1'], function(Module){
            Module.do_stuff();
        });
    });
});
```

This approach seems a bit hacky. is there a built in way to work around these race conditions?

Comment: My suspicion on this failure is that there is some sort of circular dependency somewhere. Do you think you could also post the define statements for 'hogan' and 'common_templates'?

Comment: Its not circular dependency - its race condition. Circular dependency would fail consistently, not intermittently. It would also fail at the point where I access `do_stuff` with message ~"cannot access attribute of undefined". I can also see its a race condition in the network panel.

Comment: You should explain in your question what `common_templates` contains. You've received two answers amount to exactly the same thing: mine (since deleted) and jax's. If you don't change your question to provide more details, you'll keep getting the same answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If common_templates is not an AMD module (doesn't contain a `define([deps])` call), then you need to configure it as a shim:

```
require.config({
  shims: {
     common_templates: {
      deps: ["hogan"]
     }
  } 
});
```

Now, `require(['module1', 'hogan', 'common_templates'])` and `require(['module1', 'common_templates'])` should work.

Comment: thanks, but according to the docs "[deps] does not block any other require() calls from starting their requests for modules, it is just a way to specify some modules to load asynchronously as part of a config block."

Comment: it will "block" dependant require's. E.g. in this case, it will ensure "common_templates" only loads after "hogan" finishes loading. In your case, if you want `module1` to only be loaded after `common_templates` load - you need to list `common_templates` as a dependency in `module1` or nest requires like `require(["common_templates"], function () { require(["module1"]); })`

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue. *I needed to essentially 'block' my program flow to ensure that an initial list of dependencies were loaded before a second list of dependencies, and then finally my main application code.* **Here is how I solved it**. This is the Require.js call I made in my index.html file:

```
<script src="/js/lib/require_2.1.22.js"></script>
<script>
    //debugger;
    //Load common code that includes config, then load the app
    //logic for this page. Do the requirejs calls here instead of
    //a separate file so after a build there are only 2 HTTP
    //requests instead of three.
    requirejs(['/js/common_libs.js'], function (common) {
        //debugger;
        //Ensure the the AdminLTE code and its dependencies get loaded prior to loading the Backbone App.
        requirejs(['/js/lib/adminlte.js'], function (common) {
            //debugger;
            //The main file for the Backbone.js application.
            requirejs(['/js/app/main_app.js']);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The `common_libs.js` file contains the `requirejs.config({shim:...})` stuff. The `adminlte.js` library does it's own dependency checking and will complain on the console if it does not detect it's dependencies. My problem was that it was getting loaded asynchronously with its dependencies and was causing a **race condition**.

I was able to wrap the existing code in `adminlte.js` like this:

```
//My experiments with Require.js to prevent race conditions.
define([
    'jQuery-2.1.4.min',
    'bootstrap.3.3.6',
    'jquery.slimscroll.min'
], function($, Bootstrap, SlimScroll ) {

  //Existing code goes here
  ...

  //I knew to return this value by looking at the AdminLTE code. Your mileage may vary.
  return $.AdminLTE;
});
```

That allowed me to load this library separately with its dependencies. The code in `adminlte.js` is only execute after its dependencies are loaded. Then, and only after that is complete, will `main_app.js` be loaded, along with its dependencies.

Structuring your code this way allows you to explicitly load your dependencies in batches.

---

**Editing for clarity:**

The dependencies are loaded in stages. To clarify the example above:

In the first stage jQuery, Boostrap, and the SlimScroll library are loaded, then the `adminlte.js` file is execute.

In the second stage, all other dependencies are loaded, then the `main_app.js` file is executed. `main_app.js` will  have its own defined([], ...) function that calls out the rest of the dependencies it will need loaded.

This is much more efficient than writing a nested require() call for each dependency. And, as far as I can tell from the requirejs.org website, this is the 'proper' way to load serial dependencies.

---

**Coding Update:**
I also had to wrap the code in the `jquery.slimscroll` library inside a define() statement in order to explicitly call out the that this library depends on jQuery. Otherwise it was setting up another chance at a race condition.

Comment: How is this different from the nested approach shown in the question?

Comment: The nested approach shown in the question is also loading dependencies in stages.

Answer (score -1):

This does not make sense, you said "common_templates requires hogan" but if `common_templates` requires `hogan` then `hogan` will already be loaded when the `common_templates` code starts.

Make sure `common_templates.js` is defined like this:

```
define(['hogan'], function(){
    //common_templates suff here
});
```

Comment: Yes, that's the answer I gave (which I then deleted). It makes total sense to give this answer. However, this is the comment I got from the question's author: "common_templates is not a requirejs file - rather a file defining a global object."

Comment: sorry to both for the confusion - "requires" was a bad word to use in a question involving requirejs. I have updated the question.