# Requirejs potential race conditions loading backbone and underscore

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

The error belowhappens around 1/10 refreshes when using requirejs to pull backbone and underscore from amazon s3 that is defined in the require shim located in the  */shared/common.js* file.

[image: backbone & underscore requirejs errors]

The code below is loaded in the *header.jade* file to render backbone views in the header to pull data from localstorage and determine the user's info
then load it into the header DOM

```
script(type="text/javascript").
    require(['/shared/common.js'], function (common) {
      require(['/shared-marketplace/views/global-header-view.js', '/shared-marketplace/views/quote-form-modal-view.js'], function(GlobalHeaderView, QuoteFormModalView){
        var globalHeaderView = new GlobalHeaderView({el : $('header')});
        $('.open-quote-request').on('click', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var phaseLoad = $(e.currentTarget).data('phase')
          quoteFormView = new QuoteFormModalView({'phase' : phaseLoad, 'fromNonProfilePage' : true}).$el.modal({show : true, backdrop: 'static'});
        });
      });  
    });
```

There is also code towards the page footer that also depends on */shared/common.js* to be loaded before the main page js can be loaded with all the backbone views

```
script.
require(['/shared/common.js'], function (common) {
  require(['main.js']);
  require(['/shared-marketplace/js/search-advisor.js'], function(){
    require(['/shared-marketplace/js/quote-form.js']);
  });
});
```

**Questions**

1. Is there a race condition going on between the two require calls to *common.js* which is causing the error above or is it something else?
2. What is the best way to load, via require, files that have the same dependency (i.e. *common.js*) but are in multiple places on the DOM?

Comment: if you can ensure that the variables/properties etc will not be used prior to their definition in the scope chain, you can use the following hack: https://github.com/r3wt/jqMVC/blob/master/src/app.js#L79-85

Comment: [Here's an answer that says use a shim](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21510683/3585500). (I googled race condtions with requirejs.)

Comment: @ourmandave i think you missed the part i said i was using a shim

Comment: @AleksandrLitvak where exactly are you requiring backbone and underscore..? How does the shim look like..? Why not use modules instead of nested requires..?

Comment: If your backbone and underscore are residing on amazon S3, why does your error log show errors trying to load them directly from localhost?   You should show your entire requirejs config.  Something doesn't seem right that it's trying to load them from a relative page path instead of S3.

Comment: @PerryTew thats exactly what i'm trying to solve, but i think i found the issue. I believe i was setting the require.config when i called my modules with dependencies on underscore and backbone, because of race conditions the config was either updated with the s3 locations or not so at times i called local paths instead of the s3 references. I made some updates and it looks like everything works now.

Comment: awesome.  great job figuring it out.